# How to implement fmt::Display on a generically-typed enum in Rust?

Tags: enums, formatting, rust

I have implemented my linked list using this recursive enum, but now I'd like to implement a custom display format for it

```
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum List<A> {
    Empty,
    Cons(A, Box<List<A>>),
}

impl<T> fmt::Display for List<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match *self {
            List::Empty => write!(f, "()"),
            List::Cons(x, ref xs) => write!(f, "({} {})", x, xs),  
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: std::fmt::Display` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:13:59
   |
13 |             List::Cons(x, ref xs) => write!(f, "({} {})", x, xs),  
   |                                                           ^ the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `T`
   |
   = help: consider adding a `where T: std::fmt::Display` bound
   = note: required by `std::fmt::Display::fmt`
```

**Here's the rest of my code if that matters**

```
fn cons<A>(x: A, xs: List<A>) -> List<A> {
    return List::Cons(x, Box::new(xs));
}

fn len<A>(xs: &List<A>) -> i32 {
    match *xs {
        List::Empty => 0,
        List::Cons(_, ref xs) => 1 + len(xs),
    }
}

fn map<A, B>(f: &Fn(&A) -> B, xs: &List<A>) -> List<B> {
    match *xs {
        List::Empty => List::Empty,
        List::Cons(ref x, ref xs) => cons(f(x), map(f, xs)),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let xs = cons(1, cons(2, cons(3, List::Empty)));
    println!("{}", xs);
    println!("{:?}", len(&xs));

    let f = |x: &i32| (*x) * (*x);
    let ys = map(&f, &xs);
    println!("{}", ys);
    println!("{}", List::Empty);
}
```

**Expected output**

```
(1 (2 (3 ())))
3
(1 (4 (9 ())))
()
```

---

*Really* what I'd like to see this, but I have absolutely no idea how I'd go about getting this kind of output using `fmt::Result`

```
(1 2 3)
3
(1 4 9) 
()
```

Comment: I'm primarily interested in solving the *easier* of the two problems. If we can figure out the latter of the formatting options, that's just icing.

Comment: For future reference: the exact reason for, and solution to, your problem is right there in the error message.  The first line is telling you that `T` is missing the necessary constraint, and the later notes suggest the form you can use to introduce it.

Comment: DK in hindsight it makes sense. But before seeing the accepted answer, I had no idea what those things even meant. Your comment is helpful nonetheless ^^

Comment: Well, if you run the command it suggests (rustc --explain E0277), it prints out a fuller explanation and an example to show you what it means.  I bring this up just to make sure you are now aware that the information is there.

Comment: Thanks, I really mean it. I'm currently learning using repl.it/languages/rust buy I'll get rust installed tomorrow - promise 

Comment: Note that whatever tool you are using has a pretty old version of the Rust compiler. Newer versions have much clearer presentation of error messages, which I've updated the post with. If you continue to use online resources, the [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) is a much better choice (or [my alternative](https://play.integer32.com/), which allows crates).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Solving the compiler error

You are missing a trait bound. That is, you need to tell Rust that `T` can be displayed:

```
impl<T: fmt::Display> fmt::Display for List<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match *self {
            List::Empty => write!(f, "()"),
            List::Cons(ref x, ref xs) => write!(f, "({} {})", x, xs),  
        }
    }
}
```

Note the trait bound `T: fmt::Display`. This basically means: if `T` implements `fmt::Display`, then `List<T>` implements `fmt::Display` as well.

### The icing on the cake

I am unsure whether you can get nice formatting with a recursive definition. Furthermore, Rust does not guarantee tail-call optimization, so there would always be the possibility of a stack overflow.

An alternative definition could be:

```
fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
    write!(f, "(")?;
    let mut temp = self;
    while let List::Cons(ref x, ref xs) = *temp {
        write!(f, "{}", x)?;

        // Print trailing whitespace if there are more elements
        if let List::Cons(_, _) = **xs {
            write!(f, " ")?;
        }

        temp = xs;
    }

    write!(f, ")")
}
```

Note the `?` after most `write!` macro invocations. It basically means: if this `write!` results in an error, return the error now. Otherwise, continue executing the function.

Comment: Also note that `x` changed to `ref x`.

Comment: Another helpful answer, aochagavia. Wanna take a swing at the secondary list display format?

Comment: Just wrote a function for that :)

Comment: arigatou! You've given me so many useful things to think about!

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to other answers I want to mention format alignment. Make sure to check `f.align()` if you want users to be able to align the output in a column view for instance.

```rs
enum Gender{
    Male,
    Female
}
impl fmt::Display for Gender {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match f.align() {
            None => match self {
                Gender::Male => write!(f, "male"),
                Gender::Female => write!(f, "female"),
            },
            Some(_) => f.pad(&self.to_string()), // calls this function recursively but without alignments
        }
    }
}

fn main(){
    let man = Gender::Male;
    let woman = Gender::Female;
    let width = 10;
    println!("{0:<width$} and {1:<width$}", man, woman);
}
```